# Как передать в cURL дату в формате Java Date?

Tags: php, java, android, curl, parse.com

Есть Android-приложение, оно отправляет на сервер через `Parse.com` один из параметров в формате Date:

```
HashMap<String, Object> p = new HashMap();
p.put("created", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground(f, p, v);
```

Как передать этот параметр в таком же формате, но только через cURL в PHP? Пробовал передавать в массиве строковое значение или Date в виде массива, сервер не принимает такие запросы:

```
array('created'=>'Sun Nov 12 2017 02:58:09 GMT+0300')
array('__type'=>'Date','iso'=>'2017-11-11T12:35:39.273Z')
```

Как понимаю, надо передать параметр в виде самого объекта Date, но вопрос как он будет точно выглядеть в сыром текстовом виде?

Это сам код для выполнения cURL-запроса:

```
// post fields
$post_fields = array('created'=>'здесь должно быть значение для created');
// options
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $target_url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post_fields),
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $user_agent
);
// curl
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: `Sun Nov 12 02:58:09 GMT+0300 2017`

Comment: Вообще, посмотрите в Wireshark или другом любом снифере, что оно там передаёт. Тоже самое передавайте и в php.

Comment: @Suvitruf в том то и дело, там передается дата в формате объекта, а не строковой переменной.

Comment: @Suvitruf а как сниффать данные, которые передаются через HTTPS?

Comment: В вопросе про https ни слова :C

Comment: @Suvitruf про это и речь)) разобрал на исходники приложение, загвоздка в одном этом параметре. там все сделано через одно место, дата передается не в TimeStamp и даже не в String, а в виде Java-объекта. вот и вопрос, как именно передать в стринговом виде Java-объект Date

Comment: должно быть что-то типа `{'created':{'__type':'Date', 'iso':'2017-11-11T12:35:39.273Z'}}`

Comment: @zRrr да, сам думаю, что должно быть что-то в подобном виде, но пока не подобрал правильный вариант. как понимаю, на сервере стоит парсер даты, который вытягивает из объекта значение, а если не находит, то просто выдает пустой ответ. может кто-нибудь работал с parse.com через php?

Comment: Уточните момент, что принимает сервер и в каком формате?

Comment: @Виктор как видно из Java-кода, сервер принимает на вход то, что генерирует функция `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`. проблема в том, что пока не могу подобрать точный формат данных для cURL, который передает эта функция. нужен ответ человека, который на практике работал с Parse.com (сервер использует эту технологию)

Comment: а php-api не пробовали ([пример](http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions), там есть "This is how you would call the same Cloud function using PHP").

Answer (score 3):

В `PHP` не силен, но если нужна строка вида [`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/master/parse/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseDateFormat.java#L34), то по-моему, тут надо просто привести спецсимволы (двоеточие, одиночную кавычку, дефис и точку) к формату `URL`, то есть:

```
(":") заменить на ("%3a")
("'") заменить на ("%27")
("-") заменить на ("%2d")
(".") заменить на ("%2e")
```

тогда строка из вашего `cURL` запроса примет вид:

```
$post_fields
    = array('created'=>'2017%2d11%2d17%27T%2708%3a54%3a27%2e727%27Z%27');
```

---

Может быть, имеет смысл

```
'created' заменить на 'createdAt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по исходникам SDK для Android:

- Все даты передаются в формате [`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/master/parse/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseDateFormat.java#L34).
- Нужный
  вам параметр называется [`createdAt`](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/master/parse/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseObjectCurrentCoder.java#L29).

Получается вам нужно что-то типа:

```
$post_fields = array('createdAt'=>'2017-11-17T08:54:27.727Z');
```

Comment: пробовал этот вариант, но в упор не хочет работать. похоже, что данные должны быть в формате `array('__type'=>'Date','iso'=>'2017-11-11T12:35:39.273Z')` или близким к такому. в других запросах сервер Parse.com выдает даты в таком формате.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov Не понял вас. Вы написали точно такой формат, как в моём ответе. Он не принимается сервером?

Comment: да, не пойму в чем дело. то ли в самом формате, то ли в его кодировании при передаче в строке (http_build_query).